# Allowed uppercase + digits(not at the beginning) + underscore

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to build regular expression for the following:
Allowed uppercase + digits(not at the beginning) + underscore

I did some of this regular expression, to allow just Uppercase with numbers:

```
name.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9']/g, "").toUpperCase();
```

This expression returns the `name` with uppercase and deleted the un-allowed characters.

Now, how can I complete that, to allow also underscore, and to prevent digits at the beginning?

Comment: Well, don't remove underscores, and remove digits at the beginning? `/\W|^\d/g`

Comment: Do you allow the apostrophe on purpose? You haven't stated it in your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `g` flag, meaning global, won't let you treat the first character differently. You could chain two replacements like this:

`name.replace(/[0-9]*/, "").replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9_]/g, "").toUpperCase();`

So you first remove the leading digits and then apply your original replacement.

Comment: Your regex is not removing leading digits, but just first digits?

Comment: -1 because your statement about the global modifier is just wrong